# Can Jodah, Archmage Eternal and Morophon, the Boundless make a card cost 0?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Jodah, Archmage Eternal](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Jodah%2C%20Archmage%20Eternal)'s ability says that I may pay one of each color rather than pay a spell's original mana cost

[Morophon, the Boundless](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Morophon%2C%20the%20Boundless) lets me choose a creature type and spells of that chosen type cost one of each color less to cast.

Simply, if I choose Wizards with Morophon, and I choose to pay one of each color to cast a Wizard spell with Jodah, will that creature cost 0??

Comment: Fist of Suns also does this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. If the spell has the creature type you chose for Morophon, you can cast it for {0}—it will be free.

To determine the total cost of a spell we follow [rule 601.2f](https://yawgatog.com/resources/magic-rules/#R6012f):

> 601.2f. The player determines the total cost of the spell. [...] The total cost is the mana cost or alternative cost (as determined in rule 601.2b), plus all additional costs and cost increases, and minus all cost reductions. [...] If the mana component of the total cost is reduced to nothing by cost reduction effects, it is considered to be {0}.

[Jodah, Archmage Eternal](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Jodah%2C%20Archmage%20Eternal) provides an alternative cost for the spell of {W}{U}{B}{R}{G}.

[Morophon, the Boundless](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Morophon%2C%20the%20Boundless) provides a cost reduction of (again) {W}{U}{B}{R}{G}.

We choose to use Jodah's alternative cost, and we subtract Morophon's cost reduction from it. The total cost is reduced to nothing, making the spell cost {0}.

So you get a free spell! Congratulations!

Comment: And Blades of Velis Vel will be free no matter what creature type is chosen.

Answer (score 2):

The total cost to cast a spell
= mana cost or alternative cost
+ additional costs and cost increases
- cost reductions

For creature spells of the chosen type,

- [Jodah, Archmage Eternal](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Jodah%2C%20Archmage%20Eternal)'s ability provides an alternative cost of {W}{U}{B}{R}{G}.
- [Morophon, the Boundless](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Morophon%2C%20the%20Boundless)'s ability provides a cost reduction of {W}{U}{B}{R}{G}.

So,

The total cost to cast the spell
= mana cost or alternative cost ({W}{U}{B}{R}{G})
+ additional costs (none) and cost increases (none)
- cost reductions ({W}{U}{B}{R}{G})
= Free